# Angular 5 w/Angular Material - Extracting an object property from ngFor to use in component

Tags: javascript, loops, object, angular5

```
    <div *ngFor="let player of players">
      <h4 mat-line>{{player.firstName}} {{player.lastName}} - {{player.id}}</h4>
    </div>
```

I'm doing a HTTP get call from my player.service.ts file, and then looping through the player object that gets returned, printing out the firstName, lastName and id properties in a massive player list.

I need to extract a specific player ID at a given point in the loop so that I can pass that down to a child Edit Player component that opens a modal with that specific player's information pre-filled in the form (using NgModel and a getbyId call to the API to get the player object). How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using `@angular/material`. If so, you should be able to use a click handler that loads the player data and opens up a dialog with their provided dialog service.

eg:

**Template**:

```
 <div *ngFor="let player of players">
    <h4 (click)="handlePlayerClick(player.id)"
        mat-line>
       {{player.firstName}} {{player.lastName}} - {{player.id}}
     </h4>
 </div>
```

**Component**:

```
constructor(private dialogService: MatDialog, private playerApi: PlayerApiService) { }

handlePlayerClick(playerId: string): void {
   // potentially open a MatDialog here
   this.playerApi.getById(playerId).subscribe((playerData: PlayerInterface) => { 
     const dialogConfig = {
        data: {
          playerData: playerData
        }
     } as MatDialogConfig;

     this.dialogService.open(EditPlayerComponent, dialogConfig);
   });
}
```

**Documentation**: https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api

Comment: Thank you for this. Since I was using material's dialog component, I couldn't use the Angular input property to pass down information via the template. I'll plug in this fix and work through it.

Answer (score 0):

You'd want your child component to have a property like `@Input() playerId: any;` and then simply pass it in square brackets into the child tag like so:

```
<div *ngFor="let player of players">
    <h4 mat-line>{{player.firstName}} {{player.lastName}} - {{player.id}}</h4>
    <edit-player [playerId]="player.id"></edit-player>
</div>
```